# Parsing Strange JSON Data in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

My example json data is below, I have tried to parse it however, I couldn't get the data with $response[0] or $response[1] etc... How can I parse it?

Thanks!

```
[
  {
    "Tags": [
      "diyarbakır",
      "bağlar",
      "patlama"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Tags": [
      "gazetehaberleri",
      "galatasaray lisesi",
      "kadri gürsel"
    ]
  }
]
```

**UPDATE**

```
$response = json_decode($response);

foreach($response as $key => $value){
   echo $value;
}
```

*Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Maybe put some sample code of what you have tried. In general you will parse json with json_decode

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: I have updated it @danielson317

Answer (score 2):

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);
```

by default second argument is false. by using true it forces it to associative array.

http://php.net/json_decode

Answer (score 1):

As hinted upon by Varuog, the reason you cannot access the elements properly is because you seem to be confusing the result of `json_decode()`. By default, it converts the JSON objects into PHP objects.

You should still be able to get the data using `$response[0]` and `$response[1]`, however the way you access the data from there is different.

For your current implementation, to access the "Tags" element, you must do:

```
$response = json_decode($response);

foreach($response as $key => $value){
   print_r($value->{'Tags'});
}
```

Which gives the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => diyarbakır
    [1] => bağlar
    [2] => patlama
)
```

If you set the second argument of `json_decode()` to `true`, it will convert the objects to arrays and you can access it via `$value['Tags']`:

```
$response = json_decode($response, true);

foreach($response as $key => $value){
   print_r($value['Tags']);
}
```